# How do I scan a card constantly and how do I write data onto NFC tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfc

I am using the [nfcpy](https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io) library to achieve this. I was successfully able to read the nfc tag using the nfcpy lib (code below). However, I am facing a few issues.

1. The program isn't constantly running. So I run the script with my NFC tag on my NFC reader/writer and it reads info about the tag and the program ends. I can't keep scanning the tag.
2. How can I write information to the NFC tag. For example a tag to open a url like example.com

```
import nfc
from nfc.clf import RemoteTarget
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')
target = clf.sense(RemoteTarget('106A'), RemoteTarget('106B'), RemoteTarget('212F'))
tag = nfc.tag.activate(clf, target)
print('Info about the NFC Tag:')
print(target)
print(tag)
print('---------------------')
assert tag.ndef is not None
print('Showing all records written on this card:')
for record in tag.ndef.records:
    print(record)
print('---------------------')
```

Comment: Please read the documentation about reading and writing tags. Here's a link to the relevant introductory section https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/get-started.html#read-and-write-tags.

Comment: @StephenTiedemann There is no examples about writing